# how to test ant design modal window when interacting using keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, antd, react-testing-library

i have a following component

```
const ModalComponent = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Modal title"
        centered
        visible={visible}
        onOk={() => setVisible(false)}
        onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
      >
        content
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

and this modal is closed when `ESC` key is pressed. However my test fails for some reason. My test is:

```
it("closes modal on ESC press", async () => {
    render(<ModalComponent />)

   
    expect(
      await screen.findByText(
        "content",
      ),
    ).toBeVisible();

    fireEvent.keyDown(document, { key: "Escape", keyCode: 27 });

    await waitFor(async () => {
      expect(
        await screen.findByText(
          "content",
        ),
      ).not.toBeVisible();
    });
  });
```

Element is still visible

Comment: What's the version of antd?

Comment: @slideshowp2 version 4.20.5, https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/discussions/35602 this guy is struggling with this too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since antd `modal` component use `rc-dialog`, there is a [role='dialog'](https://github.com/react-component/dialog/blob/v8.9.0/src/Dialog/Content/Panel.tsx#L112) attribute in the `div` element of `Panel` component.

Also check ["esc to close"](https://github.com/react-component/dialog/blob/v8.9.0/tests/index.spec.tsx#L146) test case, you will know the keyboard event is not added to `document`, but the element that has `.rc-dialog` className.

`antd` passes its own [`prefixCls`](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/4.22.2/components/modal/Modal.tsx#L185) to `rc-dialog` component.  So there is no `.rc-dialog` className anymore when you use `antd` modal. So we should not use `.rc-dialog` as the selector to find the element, we could use `role='dialog'` mentioned above. RTL provides a `getByRole` query to do this.

Final solution:
`index.tsx`:

```
import { Button, Modal } from 'antd';
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const ModalComponent = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>
        Open Modal
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Modal title"
        centered
        visible={visible}
        onOk={() => setVisible(false)}
        onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
      >
        content
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import { ModalComponent } from '.';

describe('ModalComponent', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    render(<ModalComponent />);
    const openModalButton = screen.getByText(/open modal/i);
    fireEvent.click(openModalButton);
    expect(await screen.findByText('content')).toBeVisible();
    const dialog = screen.getByRole('dialog');
    fireEvent.keyDown(dialog, { keyCode: '27' });
    expect(await screen.findByText('content')).not.toBeVisible();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73147451/index.test.tsx (11.646 s)
  ModalComponent
    ✓ should pass (158 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |      90 |      100 |      75 |   88.89 |                   
 index.tsx |      90 |      100 |      75 |   88.89 | 16                
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.199 s
```

package version:

```json
"antd": "^4.16.12",
```